# add a new button in a QWidget in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to add a new QPushButton to a QWidget, but it doesn't seem to have an `addWiget` method.

I am using the following code:

```cpp
  QWidget *wdg = new QWidget;
  QPushButton *btn=new QPushButton(this);

  btn->setText("text");
  
  wdg->addWidget(btn)

  wdg->show();
  hide();
```

the 6th line is giving an error

Comment: You can't add a widget to another widget. You can assign a layout to a widget and add a widget to this layout as explained [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Comment: You can also declare `QPushButton` like this: `QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("btn text");`. I don't know why you would want to `hide()` right after showing the widget though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass QWidget as parent to QPushButton.

```cpp
QWidget *wdg = new QWidget;
QPushButton *btn=new QPushButton(wdg);
```